# Replacing / Removing All Text In Multiple Sets of Characters in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

One of the result fields has multiple html references in it such as in the code below.  Currently the result set looks like:

```
Supervisor  Employee
----------- --------
Supervisor1 <td><br>Employee1<td><br>Employee2<td><br>Employee3</table>
Supervisor2 <td><br>Employee1<td><br>Employee2</table>
Supervisor3 <td><br>Employee1<td><br>Employee2<td><br>Employee3<td><br>Employee4</table>
```

Desired Output:

```
Supervisor  Employee
----------- --------
Supervisor1 Employee1 || Employee2 || Employee3
Supervisor2 Employee1 || Employee2
Supervisor3 Employee1 || Employee2 || Employee3 || Employee4
```

Sample query:

```
create table #Temp
(
    Supervisor varchar(200), 
    Employee Varchar(200), 
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES ('Supervisor1', '<td><br>Employee1<td><br>Employee2<td><br>Employee3</table>')
, ('Supervisor2', '<td><br>Employee1<td><br>Employee2</table>')
, ('Supervisor3', '<td><br>Employee1<td><br>Employee2<td><br>Employee3<td><br>Employee4</table>')
select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```

Comment: We've got data, in consumable form, and desire. What's your _specific_ question?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to remove HTML tags.  You can do so explicitly:

```
select t.*,
       replace(replace(employee, '<td><br>', ' '), '</table>', '') as employees
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking:

```
SELECT 
  Supervisor = t.Supervisor,
  Employee   = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Employee,'<td>',''),'</table>',''),'<br>',' || ')
FROM #Temp AS t;
```

**Returns:**

```
Supervisor      Employee
--------------- -----------------------------------------------------------
Supervisor1      || Employee1 || Employee2 || Employee3
Supervisor2      || Employee1 || Employee2
Supervisor3      || Employee1 || Employee2 || Employee3 || Employee4
```

You can update your data like this.

```
UPDATE #Temp 
SET Employee = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Employee,'<td>',''),'</table>',''),'<br>','||');
```